# ErrorIrresolvableConflict response when attempting to delete calendar events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

The [delete event endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) occasionally responds with a `412` / `ErrorIrresolvableConflict` status code when attempting to delete an event. The message supplied in the response is:

> The send or update operation could not be performed because the change key passed in the request does not match the current change key for the item.

The [error description for ErrorIrresolvableConflict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/responsecode#text-value) suggests that one should:

> Retrieve the updated change key and try again.

Glancing at the [event resource description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) I see the `changeKey` mentioned as a property of an event, but nothing in the [delete event endpoint docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) suggests that the changeKey needs to be supplied when deleting an event or how one would do so.

I see a couple of similar questions on SO pertaining to [sending emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105115/outlook-api-receiving-errorirresolvableconflict-when-trying-to-send-draft) and [adding attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526141/412-precondition-failed-when-add-attachments-at-same-time) but searching around yields nothing about deleting calendar events.

This error happens transiently and I have yet to find a way to consistently reproduce it. It does not seem to be related to whether the event has attachments.

This error was observed on the following request:

request-id: 05cffaf7-c422-4bfd-97ac-6ea6d1036021

Comment: Do you have "request-id" and/or "client-request-id" of the most recent failure?

Comment: yes, added it to the post

Comment: Thanks, Elyes. I found request on server end and escalated to calendaring team. They are looking into it and there is theory what is going on. I'll update when new info is available.

Comment: I appreciate that, Ivan! Looking forward to hearing back from you.

Comment: @IvanFranjic I'm also going through what looks to be very similar (same error and error message). Can you help see if it's the same issue? The request ID is b87617c5-fe04-4017-a0c2-21f3970a8e3c. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We are having similar issues (see my question here: [Getting error code `ErrorIrresolvableConflict` responses when trying to create events on a calendar using Outlook REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58663396/getting-error-code-errorirresolvableconflict-responses-when-trying-to-create-e)) when creating calendar events through the REST Api. It subsided for a bit (to only several times a day) but since January 2nd has started happening frequently again.